# html add item and show lists with using php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am new in HTML

i want to make a user list web page. The page reads user.txt and show then left column of the tabel.

And new items in which New User column will be added to user.txt list

Instead of get/post http methos i am trying to use  2 AJAX methods to communicate the server side.

After sending url with AJAX i will  call php scripts on the server side

I think first AJAX method for adding is below

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
```

However. I coulnt find the second. And i dont know how to implement

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(nm, ml) { }
function read(nam,mail) { }
</SCRIPT>

<html>
<body>

  <table border = "1">
   <thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Registered Users</th>
          <th>New User</th>
        </tr>

         <tr>
          <td></br></td>
          <td>
              <p><label>Name:
                   <input name = "name" type = "text">

              <p><label>Email:
                   <input name = "email" type = "text">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td> 
          <p></p>

           <button onclick="read()">Read users list</button>
         </td>

        <td> 
          <p></p>

          <button onclick="add(name,email)">Add user to list</button>

          <p id="demo2"></p>
        </td> 
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </thead>
  </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP? Nobody will write this all for you (not for free, at least.) You need to learn basic PHP first before diving into a project like this. Post what you've tried so far, then *specifically* where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I am getting stuck about ajax calls. there is enough php examples for me at least. dont want sb to write entire code

Comment: It's not clear to me what the exact problem is. Are you seeing some sort of error? What part of your program is not working? You say the ajax part. If so, then you need to show us the exact code you are writing to make the ajax request. If you just don't understand how to make an ajax request then first you should look at a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Ok i am checking ajax link again. I am asking how to use ajax methods to call a php scripts on the server side

Comment: For instance how can i trig server side php script(assume it exists) --> XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", add.php?name =""&email);

Comment: Shall I answer your question or you already found a solution? :)